# Google Maps Marker Clusterer - How to use infoWindow with a location index

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, markerclusterer

I have a google map that uses has a location index below it, so users can click on a location name and the infoWindow for that location pops up on the map.

I'm also using Marker Clusterer v3. At the moment clicking on an item in the index causes the infoWindow for items within a cluster to popup at the top left corner of the map.

How can I get the infoWindow to pop up at the correct location?

Here is the code I'm using so far:

```
var gmarkers = [];
var map;
var infoWindow;

(function( $ ) {
    'use strict';

    $(function () {
        initGmap();
        var openLink = $('.members-list span');
        $(openLink).click(function () {
            var index = $(this).data('markerIndex');
            infoWindow.setContent(gmarkers[index].infWinCont);
            infoWindow.open(map, gmarkers[index]);
        });
     });

})(jQuery);

function initGmap()
{
    var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map');
    var mapLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(50.5692828655824, 10.01953125);
    var mapOptions = {
      center: mapLatlng,
      zoom: 3,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
    map.minZoom = 3;
    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    // mapData and mapDataCount are loaded from a separate file
    for (var i = 0; i < mapDataCount; i++) {
        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(mapData[i].lat, mapData[i].lon);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latLng,
            map: map,
            infWinCont: mapData[i].infWin,
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
            return function() {
                infoWindow.setContent(marker.infWinCont);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            };
        })(marker, i));
        gmarkers.push(marker);
    }
    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, gmarkers);
}
```

Comment: Could you do `infoWindow.setPosition(marker.getPosition())` or `infoWindow.setPosition(gmarkers[index].getPosition())`

Comment: @duncan - `infoWindow.setPosition(gmarkers[index].getPosition())` works exactly as I want, thank you. If you add it as an answer I will mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do:

```
infoWindow.setPosition(gmarkers[index].getPosition());
```

Answer (score 0):

The InfoWindow can be given its own position:

```
  var latlng = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    position: latlng,
    content: 'content in here'
  });
```

You can also call setPosition on the InfoWindow to move it programmatically.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows#open

Answer (score 0):

One option is to add the marker to the map before opening the infowindow

```
var index = $(this).data('markerIndex');
gmarkers[index].setMap(map);
// center and zoom on the marker so it remains unclustered
map.setCenter(gmarkers[index].getPosition());
map.setZoom(18);
// programmatically "clicking" on the marker opens the infowindow.
google.maps.event.trigger(gmarkers[index], 'click');
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/skaprk5c/1/)